# What are the precise steps of processing a feature request?

Tags: discussion

There are many feature request posts on meta. Some of them turned into special features of Mathoverflow after receiving positive feedback of the community but most of them never became anything more than some suggestions on the paper.

In the latter category one can find good proposals which never implemented to the site. It seems this is not because they were unrealistic or not useful for MO but because they were just incompatible with SE model for this site.

As far as I know, MO has a degree of sovereignty in SE network but it seems there are also some limitations on the changes that MO community can make on the site. So it is good to know some general characteristics of an *acceptable* feature proposal.

A way to  a better understanding of these general characteristics is to understand the process of adding a new feature to MO in SE network.

> **Question.** What are the precise steps of processing a feature request initiated from Meta.MO? Who are the persons who will make the important decisions in this process? MO moderators, SE community managers, developers, etc.? What criterion do they usually keep in mind while deciding about possible usefulness of a typical feature request?

Comment: The sovereignity is limited primarily to owning the domain name and some of the look and feel (e.g. no ads).  The decision was made to integrate MathOverflow into the StackExchange network to use the features their later software provided.  Any change requests as a result are considered as applying to the StackExchange (StackOverflow?) network as a whole.  You might get a better answer if you asked this on meta.stackexchange.  Gerhard "At Least We're Not MathExchange" Paseman, 2015.12.31

Comment: I think a possible good answer for this question should be provided by a MO moderator or a SE community manager who knows how things work in such cases by detail. I will be thankful if any of them provide an answer for this question.